# primefaces hotkeys firing all of them

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Im doing a green screen conversion where I need to replicate about 20 or so hotkeys on each view.  I have this as the side menubar to be displayed

```
<h:form>
        <p:hotkey id="hotkeyCtlShiftA" bind="ctl+shift+a" async="true"
            update=":#{p:component('displayHotkey')}"
            action="#{hotkeyController.runCtlShiftA}" />
        <p:hotkey id="hotkeyCtlShiftS" bind="ctl+shift+s" async="true"
            update=":#{p:component('displayHotkey')}"
            action="#{hotkeyController.runCtlShiftS}" />
        <p:hotkey id="hotkeyCtlShiftD" bind="ctl+shift+d" async="true"
            update=":#{p:component('displayHotkey')}"
            action="#{hotkeyController.runCtlShiftD}" />
        <p:hotkey id="hotkeyAltF1" bind="alt+f1" async="true"
            update=":#{p:component('displayHotkey')}"
            action="#{hotkeyController.runAltF1}" />

        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked hotkeyPill">
            <li><p:commandLink id="cmdCtlShiftA"
                    update=":#{p:component('displayHotkey')}"
                    actionListener="#{hotkeyController.runCtlShiftA}"
                    style="margin-right:20px;">
                    <h:outputText value="ctl+shift+a" />
                </p:commandLink>
            </li>
            <li><p:commandLink id="cmdCtlShiftS"
                    update=":#{p:component('displayHotkey')}"
                    actionListener="#{hotkeyController.runCtlShiftS}"
                    style="margin-right:20px;">
                    <h:outputText value="ctl+shift+s" />
                </p:commandLink>
            </li>
            <li><p:commandLink id="cmdCtlShiftD"
                    update=":#{p:component('displayHotkey')}"
                    actionListener="#{hotkeyController.runCtlShiftD}"
                    style="margin-right:20px;">
                    <h:outputText value="ctl+shift+d" />
                </p:commandLink>
            </li>
            <li><p:commandLink id="cmdAltF1"
                    update=":#{p:component('displayHotkey')}"
                    actionListener="#{hotkeyController.runAltF1}"
                    style="margin-right:20px;">
                    <h:outputText value="alt+f1" />
                </p:commandLink>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </h:form>
```

Now if i click the menu button in the nav bar (the command link) it works perfectly.  But if hit the hotkey stroke, say ctl+shift+a, it fires ALL of the hotkeys, not just the A key.  Why would this be happening?

im using Primeface 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out out.  i replaced `ctl` with `ctrl` in my binding and it all came alive.  gotta love type-o's